# python classes/subclasses with mutually exclusive optional arguments using a instance of the superclass as a possible constructor

Tags: python, optional-parameters

I am trying to define in python a class B, subclass of A, that could accept multiple ways of being instantiated to be very flexible. A is a simple class with few members. I know how to write A to allow a mix of positional/keywords arguments and having default values if some arguments are omitted.

My problem comes with class B. B is simply A with an extra member. But when I create an instance of B, I would like to have the choice between:

- an instance created from a mix of positional/keyword arguments (pretty much like A)
- an instance created specifying the extra member and an existing instance (or a copy) of A
- created using only an existing instance of A and the extra member gets a default value.
- making mutually exclusive the use of an existing instance of A and positional/keywords arguments

edit: something like this

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x1=1, x2='a', x3=4.0)
        self.x1=x1
        self.x2=x2
        self.x3=x3

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x1=1, x2='a', x3=4.0, x4='t')
        self.x4=x4
        A.__init__(x1,x2,x3)
```

but then I would like to use it like this:

```
a1=A()
b1=B()         # takes all defaults
b2=B(x4='r')   # x1,x2,x3 gets defaults from A
b3=B(a1,x4='z')  # use a1, an instance of A
b4=B(x1,x2,x3,x4) # defines manually all arguments
b5=B(a1,x1=2) # this one should not work because x1 can come from the instance a1 or x1
```

Comment: provide a code example, it will be easier to help you

Comment: Your fourth example probably won't work - you can't use positional arguments after keyword args.

Comment: ok I will edit to change the position of the arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest thing is probably to define `B` with a nice straightforward initialiser with the same signature as `A` uses and then additional factory functions defined as class methods to do the more complicated scenarios. That way you won't get messed up when two different methods of construction actually take exactly indistinguishable arguments.

So something like:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, some, args):
        A.__init__(self, some, args)

    @classmethod
    def fromA(cls, theA, extra=some_default):
        newB = cls(theA.some, theA.args)
        newB.extra = extra
        return newB
```

Comment: This seems to be the path I was looking for. I will have a look at it in details. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best way of dealing with complex cases like that is to use `*args, **kwargs` and process them manually through a series of conditionals, e.g, in `B.__init__`:

```
if isinstance(arg[0], A):
    if has_other_args:
        raise TypeError
    else:
        do_something()
else:
    do_something_else()
```

However, this can still get really complicated so factory functions (as suggested by Duncan) are probably the best approach.

Side note:  Whenever I find myself in a position of wanting this sort of functionality, its usually an indication that something's not right with my design.  Even if I implement it, I usually end up replacing the entire structure with something neater.

Comment: This will be too much code to write, I will try with the factory class functions. Thanks anyway.